# Build Error (CreateEmberL10nFastBootAssetMap) when starts an Ember Project

Tags: ember.js, build, yarnpkg, hadoop-yarn

I'm trying to create my built folder for an emberJS project, but I get this error when I run the command `yarn start`

```bash
Build Error (CreateEmberL10nFastBootAssetMap)

ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir '/var/folders/2z/169nvw1959q444m88mg24prc0000gn/T/broccoli-10881ZqfXS0rWIq4v/out-861-broccoli_merge_trees//var/folders/2z/169nvw1959q444m88mg24prc0000gn/T/broccoli-10881ZqfXS0rWIq4v/out-861-broccoli_merge_trees'


Stack Trace and Error Report: /var/folders/2z/169nvw1959q444m88mg24prc0000gn/T/error.dump.027ea1cdeb583673f9f08a5e2e797c1b.log
```

Comment: can you include the content of the log in your output? 

more details will help, too -- what are you trying to do? thanks!!